# Laravel and Doppler integration. How can i sign my emails with DKIM?

Tags: laravel

I want to use Doppler for email campaigns, now, I was searching about something called DKIM and that i have to sign my emails with it in order to send my emails. How can i do so?

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and [Doppler API](https://restapi.fromdoppler.com/docs/)!

Edit: I could not find anything about Laravel and Doppler integration, this is why in here.

Comment: wait, i'm on google translate and roughly saw that Doppler API is a mailing service that expose everything through REST API right? i mean, DKIM is used on sending the actual e-mail which at this point relies on the Doppler part. i think its two separate question.. and suggestion for an outside resource is not the thing that goes well over here. voting for close.

Comment: So, it is enough to configure the DKIM inside my Doppler account? I just wanted to get it clear.

Comment: i believe so as the docs you pointed out only tell us how to manage the contact list. so, the part to send the e-mail had to be on their end i suppose.

Comment: Well, that's all i wanted to know. Thanks for it!